# How to make using JS, between "H1 and /H1" to automatically insert the text from the "Alt" of the photo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function altToH1(){ 
   document.getElementById("Obsada").innerHTML = "alt";
}
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #5bccf6;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #5bccf6;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="Obsada">
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/800px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png" alt="test test" style="width:200px;height:300px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**
The point is that without filling h1 , using Javascript, it should be automatically filled in from the "alt" text of the photo.
For example: 'h1 /h1' to replace 'h1'photo alt text' /h1'**
I am not experienced in coding so please bear with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

- The `Obsada` element seems to be missing a closing `</div>` tag
- You are trying to use `getElementById` to select an element that does not have an ID.  It has a class `class='Obsada'`
- If that element were selected you would have just replaced everything inside of it with the literal text "alt"
- you have an `altToH1()` function but you never call it anywhere, so it never runs.

So to fix these issues, I am going to:

- put a closing `<div>` tag at the end
- change the selector to properly target the elements you want
- get the `alt` text and put it where you want
- call the function to make it run

```js
function altToH1(cardElement){
  //within the passed in element, find the child elements
  const imageElement = cardElement.querySelector("img");
  const h1Element = cardElement.querySelector("h1");
  
  //Set the H1 text to be the alt text of the image
  h1Element.innerHTML = imageElement.alt;
}

//Select all the card elements
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.Obsada');

//Convert to an array, and call the function for each element, passing in the element
Array.from(cards).forEach(el => altToH1(el));
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #5bccf6;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #5bccf6;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="Obsada">
  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/800px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png" alt="test ONE" style="width:200px;height:300px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Obsada">
  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/800px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png" alt="test TWO" style="width:200px;height:300px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It only works when there is one photo. When there are several, it adds text only to the first one

Comment: Ok, my answer has been updated to work with multiples

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. It still only adds to the first picture

Comment: Double check that. It works with multiple pictures. The pictures are the same but I used different ALT text for them

Answer (score -1):

if you want to wright "alt" in h1 tag you should mentioned h1 in script code like:
document.querySelector(".Obsada h1").innerHTML ="alt"